# Ubuntu 22.04 python3.10 and boost 1.80 compile warning

Tags: python, c++, boost, python-3.10

After migrating our code to support ubuntu 22.04 with python 3.10 and latest stable boost 1.80 i cannot find the reason\solution for the compile warning.

- ubuntu 18.04 boost 1.76 python 3.6 was clean without errors\warnings

boost is build from source using the configuration

```
./bootstrap.sh  --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.10 
./b2 --prefix=/tmp/ --with-python
```

there error is cased by calling

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
```

cause the following warning:

```
/mnt/fs/users/iliak/system_clean/Strategies/../External/include/boost/python/call_method.hpp:61:26: warning: ‘PyObject* PyEval_CallMethod(PyObject*, const char*, const char*, ...)’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   61 |     PyObject* const result =
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
   62 |         PyEval_CallMethod(
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   63 |             self
      |             ~~~~          
   64 |             , const_cast<char*>(name)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   65 |             , const_cast<char*>("(" BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1ST(N, BOOST_PYTHON_FIXED, "O") ")")
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   66 |             BOOST_PP_REPEAT_1ST(N, BOOST_PYTHON_FAST_ARG_TO_PYTHON_GET, nil)
      |             ~             
In file included from /usr/include/python3.10/Python.h:130,
                 from /mnt/fs/users/iliak/system_clean/Strategies/../External/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:178,
                 from /mnt/fs/users/iliak/system_clean/Strategies/../External/include/boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13,
                 from /mnt/fs/users/iliak/system_clean/Strategies/../External/include/boost/python/args.hpp:8,
                 from /mnt/fs/users/iliak/system_clean/Strategies/../External/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from /mnt/fs/users/iliak/system_clean/Strategies/../Engine/CandlesManager.h:7:
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary work around:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

It is not ideal but until issue is fixed by boost it is acceptable by me.